# Get large artist image from last.fm xml (api artist.getinfo)

Tags: last.fm

This is the xml response from last fm:

```
<lfm status="ok">
   <artist>
      <name>Adele</name>
      <mbid>1de93a63-3a9f-443a-ba8a-a43b5fe0121e</mbid>
      <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Adele</url>
      <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/71796928.png</image>
      <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/71796928.png</image>
      <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/71796928.png</image>
      <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/71796928.png</image>
      <image size="mega">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/71796928/Adele+PNG.png</image>
      ...
```

I'm trying to echo that large image, but it doesn't return anything...

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=ARTISTNAME&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");

    $largeimg = $xml->artist->image['large'];
    echo '<img src="'.$largeimg.'" />';     
?>
```

If I just put $largeimg = $xml->artist->image; it just grabs that first image (small one). Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [PHP's children() function](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to get the artist node's children:

```
$artistTag= $xml->artist->children();
$largeImage = $artistTag[5]; // 5 is the index of the Large Image child
```