# Get artist image from last.fm XML (API artist.getinfo)

Tags: php, xml, last.fm

I wanted to ask you help I have an XML source (http://livefmhits.6te.net/nowplay.xml) it gives me the source of the song and I wanted to remove the cover through the lastfm (artist.getinfo) in echo I tried as follows:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://livefmhits.6te.net/nowplay.xml');
$artist = urlencode($xml->TRACK["ARTIST"]);     
$url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist='.$artist.&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026;
$xml2 = @simplexml_load_file($url);
if ($xml2 === false) 
{
    echo("Url failed"); // do whatever you want to do
}
else
{
    if($xml2->track->album->image[3])
    {
        echo '<img src="';
        echo((string) $xml2->track->album->image[3]);    
        echo '">';
    }
    else
    {
         echo "<img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SEsYAbASI68/VZ7xNuKy-GI/AAAAAAAAA3M/IWcGRDoXXms/s1600/capaindisponivel.png'"; // do whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

I'm not able to extract the source must be wrong echo, I like to remove the image that says "mega". I present to you the complete link
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&lang=ru&artist=COLDPLAY&api_key=ae9dc375e16f12528b329b25a3cca3ee and yet I was to do a post yours but I could not ([Get large artist image from last.fm xml (api artist.getinfo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027668/get-large-artist-image-from-last-fm-xml-api-artist-getinfo))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'm doing it in json. It's pretty much the same in XML.

First, we define the API KEY:

```
define('YOUR_API_KEY', 'b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026');
```

It's better to separate it from the code, it makes things easier if you need to reuse it somewhere else in your code. (for eg. in another function)

Then, we create the 2 functions we need to make the magic happen.

1. To query Lastfm's API and get its content, we will use CURL:

   function _curl($url)
   {

   ```
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);

        if(strtolower(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME)) == 'https')
        {
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }
   ```
2. Lastfm offers many options. Personally, I find it's easier to separate main queries into functions. But as you simply target images, here is the function I'd use:

   function lfm_img($artist)
   {
   $url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=$artist&api_key=".YOUR_API_KEY."&format=json";
   $json = _curl($url);

   ```
    $data = str_ireplace("#text", "text", $json);
    $list = json_decode($data);
    //If an error occurs...
    if($list->error)
        return 'ERROR.'. $list->error;      
    //That's where we get the photo. We try to get the biggest size first, if not we try smaller sizes. Returns '0' if nothing is found.
    if($list->artist->image[4])
        $img = $list->artist->image[4]->text;
    else if($list->artist->image[3])
        $img = $list->artist->image[3];
    else if($list->artist->image[2])
        $img = $list->artist->image[2];
    else if($list->artist->image[1])
        $img = $list->artist->image[1];
    else if($list->artist->image[0])
        $img = $list->artist->image[0];
    else
        $img = 0;

    return $img;
   ```

   }

And finally, use them:

```
$artist_query = 'Nirvana';
$artist_image = lfm_img($artist); 
//display image
echo '<img src="'. $artist_image .'" alt="'. $artist_query .'" />';
```

I think it's self explanatory here. ;)

Hope it helped!

Comment: can't seem to get this to work, is the code still valid ? Getting error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _cul()

Comment: @Bombelman simply replace  `_cul($url)` with `_curl($url)` in function `lfm_img($artist)`, that's just a typo. I edited my message.